# Div-specific element styling

Tags: css

If I want to style the elements within a div, instead of saying :

```
#divid input { ... }
#divid h1 { ... }
```

Is there a way of saying something like :

```
#divid {

  input: { ... }
  h1: { ... }

}
```

With my programming head on, the second way feels 'better' so I just wondered if it's possible to group element definitions in such a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is the use of a CSS preprocessor like [SASS/SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/).  It has been designed to clean up CSS code by allowing for syntax much like this.  In SCSS, it'd actually be:

```
#divid {
  input { }
  h1 { }
}
```

And that would be parsed out to:

```
#divid input { }
#divid h1 {}
```

Thus allowing you to write cleaner, more organized code, and letting the preprocessor handle the optimization and reworking to valid CSS.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've been stuck in a **very** web 1.0 mindset for way too long. Time to bite the bullet and learn some new stuff.

Comment: To be fair, there are lot of fads in web development.  Some pan out to have a firm place in the industry, though.  And I’d argue CSS preprocessing has demonstrated its here to stay for some time.  Likely until CSS itself changes (improves?) to the point it’s no longer needed (such as happened with CoffeeScript post-ES6).  Long story short, I’d encourage you to take it up and enjoy the benefits it’ll provide.  They extend beyond just the nesting we’ve displayed here.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly in CSS. For this, you'd need a preprocessor, which will come along with other handy things -- they virtually all support this kind of organization, including:

- Less: http://lesscss.org/
- Sass: https://sass-lang.com/
- Stylus: http://stylus-lang.com/

Comparisons: https://raygun.com/blog/css-preprocessors-examples/, https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sass-vs-less-vs-stylus-preprocessor-shootout--net-24320, etc. (Google is your friend now that you know the terms.)

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not support that. On the other hand you can use  [Sass](https://sass-lang.com),  you will need to compile to css. Visit the site in the link for more information.